# Manipulating Unbounded Integers using custom data structure

Tags: linked-list

Full disclosure, my question is pertaining to a project I am working on for my Data Structures class.  I know this is usually frowned upon, but I am hoping it may be okay due to the fact that I have the data structure itself done and I'm just seeking assistance in creating a method.

The project is to implement a custom data structure to represent unbounded integers using a custom linked list.  I cannot use the BigInteger nor LinkedList classes.  I implemented the data structure using [the IntNode class provided from the project.](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/edu/colorado/nodes/IntNode.java)

The class takes in a string of numbers, breaks it into 3 character chunks, converts those chunks into integers and stores each chunk in a custom "linked list" of IntNode objects.

For example: 123456789123 represented as 4 IntNodes, <123> <456> <789> <123>

The method I am having difficulty implementing is:

UnboundedInt multiply (UnboundedInt )
A method that multiplies the current UnboundedInt with a passed in one.  The return is a new UnboundedInt.

There is also an 'add' method which was easy to implement and I do realize I could use to handle multiplication by looping the 'add' method as many times as one of the UnboundedInt objects, however, how would I handle the loop variable when it, itself, breaches the limit of an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do realize I could use to handle multiplication by looping the 'add' method as many times as one of the UnboundedInt objects

That's not going to be the answer, because it would be too slow if either operand is non-trivial.

> There is also an 'add' method which was easy to implement

That's good, because that's going to be part of the solution.
How did you implement that?
Probably following the steps you would do if you had to do it on paper.
You can implement multiplication the same way.
How do you multiply two numbers on paper?
You multiply the number on the left with each digit on the right, one by one.
After you have the multiples by one digits, you add them.

For example, let's say you were to multiply `123456789123` with `234`. It would go like this:

```
  123456789123 * 234
  ------------
  246913578246
   370370367369
+   493827156492
  ==============
  28888888654782
```

Multiplying an `IntNode` by 1-digit numbers should be easy,
and you already have the implementation of `add`, so the complete solution is not far away. To sum it up, what you still need to implement:

- Multiply by a 1-digit number
- Multiply by 10
- Combine the above two to compute the total

Comment: I don't have the code for the add method on me, however, on a basic level, it iterates through each node of each UnboundInt object, adds them and if greater than 999, it increments the next node of one of the operands and adds a node to the answer of the appropriate 3 digit answer.

Its easy enough multiplying as in your example, but what if multiplying by an equally long UnboundInt.<br/>

For example:<br/>
<123><456><789><123><456> * <789><123><456><789><123>

or some absurdly long operands?

Comment: I used `234` as an example, but there won't be a significant change in the algorithm even if it's a longer number. You have to perform as many `add` operations as there are digits in the shorter operand. The process is the same, regardless of the length of the operands. There's no way around this, and this is guaranteed to give a correct result in a reasonable amount of time.